# SQL query for large baseball database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables containing historical data for all baseball games since 1952 (retrosheet data).

```
Game table (all games since 1952)
    +--------+------------+
    | GameID |    Date    |
    +--------+------------+
    |BOS0102 | 2015-06-01 |
    |TOR0189 | 2015-06-01 |
    |NYY0878 | 2015-06-02 |
    |BOS0105 | 2015-06-02 |
    +--------+------------+

Event table (play by play for each game)
    +---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
    | EventID |  GameID  | BatterID  | EventCode | IslAtBat        |
    +---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
    |   45352 | BOS01021 | mtrout001 | 1B        | True            |
    |   45369 | BOS01021 | mtrout001 | FO        | True            |
    |   45382 | BOS01021 | mtrout001 | X2        | True            |
    |   45398 | BOS01021 | mtrout001 | X1        | True            |
    |   45458 | BOS01021 | mtrout001 | Y9        | False           |
    +---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

If I want to compute Mike Trout batting average for his entire career:

```
/* Batting average = number hits / number at-bats
/* Codes that count in the batting average : 1B, 2B, 3B, HR */

SELECT SUM(Case EventCode IN(‘1B’, ‘2B’, ‘3B’, HR’) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘NumberHits’, 
    SUM(Case IsAtBat IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ‘NumberAtBats’,
    SELECT SUM(Case EventCode IN(‘1B’, ‘2B’, ‘3B’, HR’) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(Case IsAtBat IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ‘AVG’
    FROM events WHERE BatterID = ‘mtrout001’
```

What I'd like to do is:

For each game in the game table, compute the batting average of all batters for their last 25 at bats **before** the game and insert the result in a new table:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------+
|  GameID  |  BatterID  | Last25AtBatAverage|
+----------+------------+-------------------+
| BOS01021 | mtrout001  | .352              |
| BOS01021 | jdoe001    | .212              |
| BOS01021 | mjohnson   | .119              |
| BOS01021 | yhong001   | .326              |
| BOS01021 | rthoip001  | .280              |
| BOS01021 | qwillis001 | .096              |
| BOS01021 | agort001   | .257              |
| BOS01021 | bmay001    | .418              |
| BOS01021 | yhong001   | .326              |
| STL03023 | pdupuis001 | .256              |
| STL03023 | jwarren001 | .228              |
+----------+------------+-------------------+
```

This would tell me that for his last 25 at-bats before the 2015-06-01 game in Boston, Mike Trout batting average was .352

What would be the best way to proceed? Even the smallest query is taking a lot of time because of the huge amount of data.

Comment: You can't, reliably.  There is nothing to explicitly tell you what order the events happened in a game. If some one is at bat say 4 times a game, the last 25 would be 4 from each of the last 6 games, and the last from the game before that.  The event id isn't reliable for determining time order. You should add an event time column.  Then for slow queries, consider which indexes you need.  *(Also, unfortunately, mysql sucks at greatest-n-per-group, there are many answers for that tag though...)*

Comment: @MatBailie very good point! Let's say I can add that column, do you think I can manage to create a query that doesn't use cursors or loop?

Comment: Search SO for greatest n per group. There are no "pretty" ways to do it in mysql.

Comment: Nice question. Since it is a oneshot operation and that simple queries take a long time, a procedure would be a good choice to create your table... Why would you avoid cursors and loops ?

Comment: @MatBailie Ok I'll search for that, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasG Actually I don't mind using cursors and loops. :) When I use them there is always a SQL guru who shows me how to do it more efficiently